# how to execute a command in selenium ide using keyboard

Tags: selenium, keyboard-shortcuts, selenium-ide

Is there any way to run each command using my keyboard like hitting enter to execute a command?

Right now I have to double click my left mouse button to execute a command in Selenium IDE.  Just imagine I have a lot of these, that's a lot of clicking!  I would like to hit my arrow key down (which works) and hit a letter, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + some letter, or <kbd>enter</kbd> to execute the command.

I know Selenium IDE can run it slowly, but I would like this feature so I'm in the driving seat and controlling the list of commands

Is there anyway?  I can't find a plugin as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute a highlighted command, hit the <kbd>X</kbd> key. So you could cycle through the test hitting <kbd>X</kbd> to execute the command, then <kbd>Down</kbd> arrow to go to next command. repeat until done.

Klendathu

Comment: ty Klendathu, you saved me from carpal tunnel syndrome :), can't believe I haven't seen this anywhere in google and it doesn't mention on Selenium IDE at all.

Comment: No problemo.  I find it useful to walk through sections of tests when I'm building them. Note that you can also use "b" to toggle on/off a breakpoint, and "s" to toggle on/off a start point.